# Does resizing partitions cause damage?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, defragment

I plan on resizing already-separated partitions. Let's say that there is partition A and partition B on drive C:. All of drive C: is NTFS, and drive C: is, in total, 1 TB. Partition A has 400 GB, and partition B has 600 GB. If I were to make Partition A to 600 GB, and partition B to 400 GB, that shouldn't be hard. Load up any tool to resize it, and presto!

However, since the drive C: is being used every day, C: will be fragmented. My question is, if drive C: is fragmented, wouldn't 'blocks' that are stranded elsewhere, during resizing, be improperly 'transfered' to the other partition?

Comment: *"Let's say that there is partition A and partition B on drive C:."* -- That makes no sense at all.  Drive letters are mapped one-to-one to partitions.

Comment: it's not 1:1. 
In windows you could have...

::Disk(0),Partition(0)Drive(C:\)
::Disk(0),Partition(1)Drive(C:\foo\Bar\)
::Disk(1),Partition(0)Drive(C:\Bar\Foo\)
::Disk(n)Partition(n)Drive(Some UUID)

Comment: Don't get me started on .VHD's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume will be defragged before the resizes happens.  Although, even if the volume was for some reason was not defragged the only real issue would be the Read/write head would have to travel more to get access some of the sectors. decreasing your sequential reads.

Comment: No partition resizing tool I've ever seen does a complete defrag first. they might do a little defragmenting, but mostly they only move extents as necessary to fit within the new boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

No. Any tool that resizes partitions will deal correctly with fragmented files.